# Mocking class which depends on Singleton

Tags: java, unit-testing, oop, mocking, singleton

- Class A -> This is the class I want to test; It depends on class B
- Class B -> This class is supposed to be mocked; Methods of this class
  calls methods of class C
- Class C -> Singleton class

How should I test A so that tests won't invoke actual class C methods?

Comment: Please share some code. The question is a bit too general to properly answer in its current form.

Comment: Without refactoring you could use PowerMockito which allows mocking static test methods.

Comment: I don't think that tests should have to worry about this.  Tests test functionality, they do not worry about where it comes from.

Comment: When class B is mocked, then you never reach class C.

Comment: Oh, thank you guys. So it never reaches C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)